# how to iterate through an array to create a new associative array with php using laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, pivot

how to iterate through an array to create a new associative array with php for inserting into a pivot table in laravel

e.g.
    $arr = [3, 2, 3] // this are product quantities of products in a cart

and want to add them to an associate array to be something like

```
$arr = ('quantity'=> 1)
```

so i tried to iterate through the array and add elements into a new array and adding the value but keeping the same key which is required by laravel pivot

$newArr = array();

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
 $newArray[] = array('quantity' => $value);
}
```

but this an array and sub arrays.

Thank you

Comment: You are aware that you can't have an array where every key is the same (`quantity`)?

Comment: change your input example and show us what expected outcome you want based on that input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With what you tried; you will always get only one Element in your Resulting Array (the last element: to be precise). This is because the key is the same and each subsequent Key overrides the previous one.

In this case, if you need an associative array; you may have to live with a Multidimensional array so long as you wish to have quantity as the key. Otherwise you could simply either prefix or suffix the key to get a single Associative array. The Code Snippet below might be insightful:

```
    <?php

        $arr        = [3, 2, 3];
        $arrMD      = [];
        $arrAssoc   = [];

        foreach($arr as $k=>$qty){
            // CREATE A SUFFIXED KEY:
            $key            = "quantity_{$k}";
            $arrAssoc[$key] = $qty;
        }

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($arrAssoc);
        echo "</pre>";
        // YIELDS
        Array
            (
              [quantity_0] => 3
              [quantity_1] => 2
              [quantity_2] => 3
            )

        foreach($arr as $k=>$qty){
            // CREATE A TEMPORARY ARRAY
            // TO BE USED IN GENERATING THE MULTIDIMENSIONAL ARRAY:
            $tmp            = ["quantity"=>$qty];
            $arrMD[]        = $tmp;
        }

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($arrMD);
        echo "</pre>";
        //YIELDS:::
        Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                [quantity] => 3
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                  [quantity] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                  [quantity] => 3
                )
        )
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that help a lot